# Working with atoi

Tags: c, atoi

I have been attacking atoi from several different angles trying to extract ints from a string 1 digit at a time.

**Problem 1 - Sizing the array**
Should this array of 50 chars be of size 50 or 51 (to account for null terminator)?

```
char fiftyNumbersOne[51] = "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250";
```

**Problem 2 - atoi output**

What am I doing wrong here?

```
char fiftyNumbersOne[51] = "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250";
int one = 0;
char aChar = fiftyNumbersOne[48];
printf("%c\n",aChar);//outputs 5 (second to last #)
one = atoi(&aChar);
printf("%d\n",one);//outputs what appears to be INT_MAX...I want 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The array should be length 51.  But you can avoid having to manually figure that out by simply doing `char fiftyNumbersOne[] = "blahblahblah";`.

**Problem 2**

`aChar` is not a *pointer to the original string*; it's just an isolated `char` floating about in memory somewhere.  But `atoi(&aChar)` is treating it as if it were a pointer to a null-terminated string.  It's simply walking through memory until it happens to find a `0` somewhere, and then interpreting everything it's found as a string.

You probably want:

```
one = aChar - '0';
```

This relies on the fact that the character values for `0` to `9` are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  One last question.  Why is it that to get the last character in my string I need to use index 49?  I thought it would be index 50...?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, because arrays are zero-based in C.  The first element has index 0, the second has index 1, etc, the nth element has index n-1.

Comment: @P.Brian: Because arrays are *0-based* in C.  So the first element is `x[0]`, the second is `x[1]`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Oli.  I got a little thrown off by the arrays coming from C#.  Its similar, but having that null terminator throws me off.  I need more practice.

Answer (score 3):

1. 51.
2. That's because `aChar` is not null-terminated. If you just want to get the integer value of a `char`, simply use

   ```
   one = aChar - '0';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> Problem 1 - Sizing the array Should
>   this array of 50 chars be of size 50
>   or 51 (to account for null
>   terminator)?

You always want an array one bigger than what you need to store in it (to account for the null terminator). So your 50 chars should be stored in an array of size 51.

> What am I doing wrong here?

Try null terminating your input string to atoi. Documentation says atoi is supposed to be given the pointer to a string - which is different than a non-terminated single character. Your results with the current code you posted vary on different platforms (I get -1 on unbuntu/gcc) .

```
char fiftyNumbersOne[51] = "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250";
int one = 0;
char aChar = fiftyNumbersOne[48];
char intChar[2];
printf("%c\n",aChar);//outputs 5 (second to last #)
sprintf(intChar, "%c", aChar); //print the char to a null terminated string
one = atoi(&intChar);
printf("%d\n",one);//outputs what appears to be INT_MAX...I want 5
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should this array of 50 chars be of size 50 or 51 (to account for null terminator)?

51, but you can also declare it without size.

```
char foo[] = "foo";
```

> What am I doing wrong here?

Not reading the documentation for `atoi` I guess.  `aChar` is a `char`, so you're passing the right type to `atoi`, but `atoi` is expecting this type to represent a string of characters, normally terminated by the character '\0'.  Your "string" isn't terminated.

One solution to this is

```
char aString[2];
aString[0] = fiftyNumbersOne[48];
aString[1] = '\0';
atoi(aString);
```

Another is doing `fiftyNumbersOne[48] - '0'` instead of calling `atoi`, since in ASCII the decimal codes are consecutive and increasing from 0 to 9.